# Getting Error Fatal error during compilation org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException: Compilation Failed. in grails app

Tags: grails

When I run grails run-app through terminal or using Grails/Groovy tool suite, it gets "compilation error" with

```
`Error Fatal error during compilation org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException: Compilation Failed (Use --stacktrace to see the full tr`ac`e)
```

.

I am using grails 2.0. Below is what happen when I run grails run-app through ubuntu terminal.

```
    Loading Grails 2.0.0
    | Configuring classpath.
    | Environment set to development.....
    | Packaging Grails application
    > You currently already have a version of the plugin installed [hibernate-2.0.0]. Do you want to update to [hibernate-3.6.10.2]? [y,n] n
    | Plugin hibernate-3.6.10.2 install aborted
    > You currently already have a version of the plugin installed [tomcat-2.0.0]. Do you want to update to [tomcat-7.0.42]? [y,n] n
    | Plugin tomcat-7.0.42 install aborted
    > You currently already have a version of the plugin installed [release-2.2.1]. Do you want to update to [release-3.0.1]? [y,n] n
    | Plugin release-3.0.1 install aborted
    | Plugin release-3.0.1 install aborted..
    Compiling 4 source files.
| Error Fatal error during compilation org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException: Compilation Failed (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace
```

)

**BuildConfig.groovy**

```
grails.servlet.version = "2.5" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // uncomment to disable ehcache
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "error" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins
        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        grailsCentral()
        mavenCentral()

        // uncomment these to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
        //mavenCentral()
        //mavenLocal()
        //mavenRepo "http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }
    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes eg.

         runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.16'
    }


    plugins {
        build ':release:2.2.1', ':rest-client-builder:1.0.3', {
      export = false
   }
        runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
        runtime ":jquery:1.7.1"
        runtime ":spring-security-core:1.2.7.2"
        runtime ':resources:1.2'
        runtime ":cached-resources:1.0"
        runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0"
        compile ":cache-headers:1.1.5"
        build ":tomcat:2.0.0"
        //compile ":attachmentable:0.3.0"
        compile ":searchable:0.6.4"
        compile ":cloud-bees:0.6.2"

        compile ":jquery-validation:latest.release"
        compile ":jquery-validation-ui:latest.release"
        compile ":twitter-bootstrap:2.3.2"
        compile ":lesscss-resources:1.3.3"
        runtime ":fields:1.3"
        compile ":mail:1.0.1"
        compile ":jquery-ui:1.8.24"
        compile ":spring-security-ui:0.2"
        compile ":mail:1.0"
        compile ":famfamfam:1.0"
        compile ":spring-security-acl:1.1.1"



    }
}
```

When I run grails run-app, It always ask for updating tomcat and hibernate plugings to latest version. I dont know why this is happening. Any suggestion on this.

Can It related to tomcat and hibernate plugin versons?

**application.properties**

```
    #Grails Metadata file
    #Thu Nov 14 15:09:35 IST 2013
    app.grails.version=2.0.0
    app.name=VProcureFinal
    app.servlet.version=2.5
    app.version=0.1
    plugins.avatar=0.6.3
    plugins.burning-image=0.5.1
    plugins.class-diagram=0.5.2
    plugins.jquery-validation-ui=1.4.4
    plugins.prototype=1.0
    plugins.richui=0.8
plugins.webxml=1.4.1
```

**grails run-app out**put:

```
 grails run-app
| Packaging Grails application
> You currently already have a version of the plugin installed [tomcat-2.0.0]. Do you want to update to [tomcat-7.0.42]? [y,n] n
| Installed plugin release-3.0.1
| Error Plugin release-3.0.1 requires version [2.3 > *] of Grails which your current Grails installation does not meet. Please try install a different version of the plugin or Grails.
| Installed plugin release-3.0.1
```

.

Comment: Not sure but grails clean solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

A couple of suggestions. The most likely answer is applications.properties specifying something different to BuildConfig.groovy.

1. You are running 2.0.0. How about at least trying 2.0.4 as there would be bug fixes?
2. BuildConfig.groovy doesn't look like the authoritative source. e.g. tomcat is specified as 2.0.0 specifically so you don't have the typical upgrade problem, where in 2.3.x these plugins moved from $grailsVersion.

   Check application.properties. The grails version in there will be 2.0.0 - can see this from the startup. The tomcat and hibernate versions may be specified here as the versions you see in the startup.
3. grails clean and/or delete .grails directory in your home directory.

Comment: hi @interlated, I have added application.properties file. Please have a look at this.

Comment: hi @interlated, I just uninstalled -plugin release 2.2.1, Now automataclly -plugin release 3.0.1 has been installed to my system. Why this is happening . any idea?

Comment: Yes - use BuildConfig.groovy or application.properties - not both.

Comment: hi @interlated why  Installed plugin release-3.0.1. get installed automatcally to application on failure of grails run-app.I have updated question. Could you look at this.

Comment: hi @interlated, can we specify grails version in BuildConfig.groovy?

Comment: Plugin :release it could be a dependency of something. Clean out application.properties first and run grails clean. That gets rid of most of the ambiguity. In BuildConfig you can either comment out each dependency and try by elimination or set "log = debug" and trawl through the dependency output.

Comment: Grails version. This is specified in application.properties and grails will ask you to upgrade if you have something different in the $GRAILS_HOME environment variable. $GRAILS_HOME or what you set your IDE to use is key.